# Gold packs on of Fifa 14

Tags: fifa-14

Little late in the day, but thinking of buying Fifa 14. When my friend got it, it came with two of the “gold packs,” does anyone know if they still do?

I cannot see anywhere in the descriptions that they do on websites, wondering if anyone bought a copy recently and got packs. Or have I got how they work completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to get card packs:

> The FIFA 14 Ultimate Team Cards are created by EA that places them into the game by four methods:
>
> - when registering a new team (‘starter pack’);
> - when purchasing packages in the store;
> - when winning tournaments or seasons whose prizes are packages;
> - or when get Daily Gifts, Welcome Back packs and other prizes;
>
> [Source](http://www.fifauteam.com/fifa-14-ultimate-team-cards-guide/)

There was also a recent celebration for the fifth birthday of FIFA Ultimate Team where gold packs were given away for free:

> EA has decided to shower FIFA Ultimate Team players in a frenzy of free cards to celebrate its fifth birthday.
>
> Players can now login to the game on PC or console and scoop up five Gold Rare packs for free by clicking on the anniversary banner
>
> [Source](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/here-s-how-to-get-your-five-free-fifa-ultimate-team-card-packs/1100-6418424/)

I don't believe the game comes with gold packs. Your friend probably received them as a "start-up pack" when he registered a new team.

I have done some research and found nothing on card packs coming bundled with the game. If I were you I would ask your friend how he got them, otherwise just sit tight for another card pack giveaway event!

Comment: Thank you, I think I will buy it, register a new team and see how it goes

Comment: was just about to haha